# Как добавить дочерний элемент в начало?

Tags: javascript

```
var im = document.createElement("img");
im.src = 'imag/1.png';
document.getElementById('myid').appendChild(im);
```

Этот код добавит элемент img в конец детей элемента 'myid', а как сделать чтоб добавлял в начало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[insertBefore](http://www.dhtml.ru/ref/dom/methods/insertbefore/) для добавления перед нодой (любой, в вашем случае первой).

```
// Get a reference to the element in which we want to insert a new node
var parentElement = document.getElementById('parentElement');

// Get a reference to the first child
var theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild;

// Create a new element
var newElement = document.createElement("div");

// Insert the new element before the first child
parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, theFirstChild);
```

Answer (score 2):

вставьте новый элемент перед первым потомком.

```
var im = document.createElement("img");
im.src = 'imag/1.png';
var element = document.getElementById('myid');

element.insertBefore(im, element.firstChild);
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SY9ws/)

Comment: Так вроде надо не перед myid, а первым дитём myid...

Comment: тогда еще проще

Comment: `parent.firstChild` может вернуть `TextNode`, а это создаст проблемы

----------
может поехать вёрстка, это хорошо заметно при практическом использовании

Comment: @Gedweb [какие](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SY9ws/3/) ?

Comment: что значит "поехать" img вставится перед текстом, ну и вообще, это проблема верстальщика, `<span>` ничем не отличается в этом смысле, ваше решение эту проблему никак не обходит. если об этом думать, то надо для каждого конкретного случая какие-то правила вводить,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SY9ws/4/ считается ли это непоехавшей версткой ?

Comment: @eicto, вы на столько любите спорить что даже смешно ))) #close

Answer (score 1):

```
par=document.getElementById('myid');
par.insertBefore(im, par.children[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var New_Element = document.createElement("div");

parent.insertBefore(New_Element, parent.firstElementChild);
```